# get taggable friends on facebook sdk 4.0+

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with the list of taggable friends, this is my code , that with the old sdk worked great.

```
       public void getTaggableFriends(){
        Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if(activeSession.getState().isOpened()){
        new Request(
                activeSession,
                "/me/taggable_friends",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                        GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        if (graphObject != null) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                            String taggableFriendsJson = jsonObject.toString();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            TaggableFriendsWrapper taggableFriendsWrapper= gson.fromJson(taggableFriendsJson, TaggableFriendsWrapper.class);
                            ArrayList<TaggableFriends> invitableFriends = new ArrayList<TaggableFriends>();
                            invitableFriends = taggableFriendsWrapper.getData();
                            int i;
                            for(i = 0; i < invitableFriends.size(); i++)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                MainActivity.myMenu.add(invitableFriends.get(i).getName());
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){}
                            }
                            MainActivity.myMenu.add("Tot: " + i);
                        }else {

                        }
                        //response.get

                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
        }
    }
```

get to the point , how can I adapt SDK 4.0 ? Or is there some other way to do this ?? I would not know where to start, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change it to

```
if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null)
{
    GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "me/taggable_friends",
            new GraphRequest.Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse)
                {
                    //Your code

                    if(graphResponse != null)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
                            String taggableFriendsJson = jsonObject.toString();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            TaggableFriendsWrapper taggableFriendsWrapper= gson.fromJson(taggableFriendsJson, TaggableFriendsWrapper.class);
                            ArrayList<TaggableFriends> invitableFriends = new ArrayList<TaggableFriends>();
                            invitableFriends = taggableFriendsWrapper.getData();
                            int i;
                            for(i = 0; i < invitableFriends.size(); i++)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    MainActivity.myMenu.add(invitableFriends.get(i).getName());
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){}
                            }
                            MainActivity.myMenu.add("Tot: " + i);
                        }else {

                        }
                        //response.get

                }
            }
        );

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putInt("limit", 5000); //5000 is maximum number of friends you can have on Facebook

        graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
        graphRequest.executeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! only a question as never before came back to me 650 or something friends and now only 25 ? Is anything changed in GraphAPI ?

Comment: yes, it is limited to 25, give me a minute, I'll change the code to work around that :)

Answer (score 0):

Now it wont work

As of facebook doc the User Taggable Friend node was deprecated on April 4th, 2018 and now returns an empty data set.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/